# How to make AppleScript simulate the keypress for "1" key?

Tags: input, applescript, key, output

I am trying to simulate pressing the key <kbd>1</kbd> within a Java application. I have tried using key code 18, text to type, key down and keystrokes but whatever I try, the application displays the `a` character. Even when the script types into applescript window I just get `aaaaaaa`.

What am I doing wrong and how to properly simulate keypresses with AppleScript?

Comment: I use the free "Key Codes" application to get the codes for any pressed key [ http://manytricks.com/keycodes/ ]

Comment: i downloaded that but even using key code 18  for the 1 key doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Did you try anything like the following?

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "1"
end tell
```

You can pass string literals to System Events `keystroke`-Handler

Comment: thank you, that does yield a "1" however i would now like to hold down the 1 key for 0.2 seconds and then release it.    "tell application "System Events"
 key down "1"
 delay 0.2
 key up "1"
end tell"       this still yields an "a".(apologies; i don't know how to format this stuff) thanks

Comment: I found this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472368/applescript-press-and-hold-⌘-f2-for-5-seconds) and unfortunately it seems like it will not work the way you want :(